# Why i am getting last value of an array in spinner?

Tags: android

Why i am getting only last value of an array. My array "arr" contains list of values but when i use it in spinner i am getting only last value of an array. Thanks in advance!!!

```
  public void addItemsOnSpinner2(String[] arr) {
        List list = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(arr));
        //System.out.println("Function Currency value===>"+list);
        System.out.println("Function Currency value===>"+Arrays.toString(arr));

        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }

List<Currency> dataList = currencyExchange.getCurrencyList();
        Iterator<Currency> iterator = dataList.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            try {
                //System.out.println("hhhhhhhhhhh=>" + iterator.next().getName());
                currencyName= iterator.next().getName();
                //String[] words=currencyName.split(" ");
            arr=currencyName.split(" ");
            System.out.println("Currencyname==>"+ Arrays.toString(arr));
            }
            catch (NoSuchElementException e){
                System.out.println("Continue");
            }
            addItemsOnSpinner2(arr);

        }
```

Comment: show me more code

Comment: where you setAdapter(dataAdapter) Spinner?

Comment: Please check it i have updated my code

Answer (score 0):

> The reason you are only getting last value because in while loop you are using
>   one variable, so when you update new value of iterator into it, it is
>   replaced by old value

Convert your **iterator** to **ArrayList** like this :

```
Iterator<Currency> iterator = dataList.iterator();
List<String> arList= Lists.newArrayList(iterator);
```

Then call your method **addItemsOnSpinner2(String[] arr)** like this :

```
addItemsOnSpinner2(arList);
```

***Edit:***

Replace

```
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        try {
            //System.out.println("hhhhhhhhhhh=>" + iterator.next().getName());
            currencyName= iterator.next().getName();
            //String[] words=currencyName.split(" ");
        arr=currencyName.split(" ");
        System.out.println("Currencyname==>"+ Arrays.toString(arr));
        }
        catch (NoSuchElementException e){
            System.out.println("Continue");
        }
        addItemsOnSpinner2(arr);
```

with

```
String[] arr = dataList.toArray();
addItemsOnSpinner2(arr);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply ,I am not getting your point what you want to say. i am already getting list of value in array under addItemsOnSpinner2(){} method but when i tried it in spinner it shows only last element of array

Comment: Thanks you, it show error incompatible type, required String[], found Object[]. when i changed it to Object[] it shows array value in spinner in object format

Comment: Did it solve your problem? If yes then kindly accept my answer

Comment: not solve.  it show error incompatible type, required String[], found Object[].

Comment: cast it to String[] instead of Object[]

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to java.lang.String[]

Comment: List<Currency> dataList = currencyExchange.getCurrencyList(); it returns List of Currency type.

Comment: Try replacing your method parameters from **String[] arr** to **Object[] arr**